# Is it possible to achieve Conscentious Objector as a solo player?

Tags: achievements, castle-crashers

The Conscientious Objector achievement is earned by playing from Home Castle to Barbarian Boss without attacking any enemies.

Considering that you can't advance each battle until all enemies are killed (the entire point of, you know, battling), does that make it impossible to achieve without playing with friends? Or can you rely on damage-dealing pets to attack enemies for you as an exception to the achievement requirement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this achievement the game looks at the experience points, if it's increased you won't get the achievement. Only Rammy's headbutt and Red Knight's splash attack against a wall won't give you any experience points.

There are two ways to get this achievement solo:

- Use Rammy to deal all damage to enemies. Use Red Knight's splash for War Machine (mini-boss) and Barbarian Boss because they count as walls. Do note that takes a very long time to do and if you mess up by hitting an enemy once with Red Knight's splash you have to start over.
- By using two controllers. Use the character you do NOT want to earn the achievement with to beat the level. This is the recommended way.

[More info on a wiki](https://castlecrashers.fandom.com/wiki/Conscientious_Objector).

Video of Zumbee doing it solo, the boss fight is long because this is the first ever completion:
[image]